# Monogames can't add SharpDx Dll

Tags: c#, dll, windows-phone-8, sharpdx

Yo,

I have follow this tuto step by step : http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/XNA_Games_On_Windows_Phone_8_with_Monogame

But still not working.
errors message : `Warning   8   The referenced component 'SharpDX' could not be found.  MonoGame.Framework.WindowsPhone`

or

Warning 4   The referenced component 'SharpDX.WP8' could not be found.  MonoGame.Framework.WindowsPhone

i have deduce SharpDx was missing (obvious), but when i try to add the reference using Nuggetsmanagepacket; I have the following message :

```
Installing 'SharpDX 2.5.0'.
Successfully installed 'SharpDX 2.5.0'.
Adding 'SharpDX 2.5.0' to MonoGame.Framework.WindowsPhone.
Uninstalling 'SharpDX 2.5.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'SharpDX 2.5.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'SharpDX 2.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Any Idea about what the problem, no awnser on Wiki_nokia website.
I have WP8 Sdk, and i'm using full version of Visual studio express 2012 (on Windows 8 )

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately nuget packages [don't support](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/174) platform specific builds of SharpDX. You need to add all references manually.